# C++/Qt, OpenGL texture mapping

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, mapping, textures

I'm attempting to render a texture that has been mapped to the graphics video memory.  I have used qDebug to test that input of my image, indeed it possesses a 512x512 image which is a power of 2.  Yet still when I attempt to render, instead of a texture the result is merely a quad which is white.

To note: GLuint m_textureIdents[1]; is correctly defined in GLWidget.h

```
#include "GLWidget.h"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
    m_sceneIndex = SinQuest::SplashScreen;
}

void GLWidget::setApplicationPath(QString strAppPath)
{
    m_strAppPath = strAppPath;
}

#include <QDebug>
void GLWidget::loadResources(void)
{
    m_imageHandler.addImage(QString(m_strAppPath).append(QDir().toNativeSeparators("\\resources\\images\\")).append("splash_logo.png"), "splash-logo");
    QImage glImageData = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(*m_imageHandler.getImage("splash-logo"));

    qDebug() << glImageData.width() << ":" << glImageData.height();

    m_textureIdents[0] = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &m_textureIdents[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureIdents[0]);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, glImageData.width(), glImageData.height(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, glImageData.bits());
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, w, 0, h, -1.0l, 1.0l); // set up origin
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glShadeModel( GL_FLAT );
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureIdents[0]);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2i(0, 0);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2i(512, 0);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2i(512, 512);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2i(0, 512);

    glEnd();
}

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {

}
void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", event->x(), event->y());
}

void GLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
    switch(event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Escape:
        close();
        break;
    default:
        event->ignore();
        break;
    }
}
```

...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDesktopWidget *pDeskWidget = app.desktop();

    // available geometry to obtain resolution for primary screen
    QRect avGeometry = pDeskWidget->availableGeometry(pDeskWidget->primaryScreen());

    // create window, set resolution and invoke fullscreen window state
    GLWidget window;
    window.setApplicationPath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
    window.loadResources();
    window.resize(avGeometry.width(), avGeometry.height());
    window.setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Where you're setting up your texture parameters, have you tried `glTexEnvi (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);`?

Comment: I've added that line and there is no change.

Comment: Where are you calling GLWidget::loadResources?

Comment: I can creating an instance of GLWidget from a file called main.cpp:

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by changing the order of window.loadResources and window.show.  Window.show invokes the opengl init function which resultantly prunes the video memory of any texture that may have been loaded prior.